# HttpClient's GetMethod does'nt work with redirects

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, getmethod

So I am trying to invoke a GET request to the link

```
https://captivate.taps.com/auth/authorize?client_id=7b3fe4ba-3c3d-4fbf&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4502/ats/GetCode.html
```

This link will authorize the client_id and redirect to the provided url with a parameter "code" appended to the url.

The code to invoke the GET request is-

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    String url = "https://captivate.taps.com/auth/authorize?client_id=7b3fe4ba-3c3d-4fbf&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4502/ats/GetCode.html";
    GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
    getMethod.setFollowRedirects(true);
    int getStatus = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
```

The redirected url - `http://localhost:4502/ats/GetCode.html` has the code-

```
    String authCode = request.getParameter("code");
    GetAccessToken.code = authCode; // GetAccessToken is a class with a static String "code".
```

The problem is when I fire the link using the browser, the GetCode.html is invoked and the authorization code is assigned but when i do the same using the code provided GetCode.html is never invoked.

Update: All I want here is to capture the redricted url so that I can get the Authorization code from it

Comment: How is the redirect on `captivate.taps.com` performed? HTTP 302, thorugh JavaScript, HTML meta, ...?

Comment: @Jiri - its HTTP 302